# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 at Comment.main(Comment.java:13)

Tags: java

I have Written a program to identify whether a given line is a comment or not. the program is working correctly but when the user enters single slash (/) he gets a message says "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at Comment.main(Comment.java:13)" instead of is a comment or not.
Help me I want to discover this problem.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Comment {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char com[]=new char[30];
        int i=2,a=0;
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
        System.out.println("\n\n\n Enter comment: \n"); 
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        com = reader.next().toCharArray();
        if(com[0]=='/'){
            if(com[1]=='/')         
                System.out.println("\n It is a comment");
            else if(com[1]=='*'){
                for(i=2;i<=30;i++){
                    if(com[i]=='*'&&com[i+1]=='/'){
                        System.out.println("\n It is a comment");
                        a=1; break;
                    }
                    else 
                        continue;
                }
                if(a==0) 
                    System.out.println("\n It is not a comment"); 
            }   
            else 
                System.out.println("\n It is not a comment"); 
        }
        else 
            System.out.println("\n It is not a comment");
    }
}
```

Comment: which line is line no. 13?

Comment: Did you use a dubugger and walked step by step?

Comment: line no.13 is the line written this code  " if(com[1]=='/')  "

Comment: yes, it works but the problem is when the user enters single slash (/).

Comment: `com = reader.next().toCharArray();` reallocate a new array with length == 1 for '/' input

Comment: Ok @Aubin how can I Update to success a program results if the line is a comment or not

Comment: To parse a complex text file, you need to study more than arrays.
An excellent book is the "dragon book", it takes months to understand all the techniques but it's worth it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools

Answer (score 2):

> "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 at Comment.main(Comment.java:13)"

It means:

```
if(com[0]=='/'){
    if(com[1]=='/')         
        System.out.println("\n It is a comment");
    // your code
}
```

If the user only enters slash (/), then input (`com`) is of length 1 (one character only). You can only access index 0 through `com[0]`.

So, you will not get any value at index 1 through `com[1]`. If you try to access `com[1]`, you will get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

To understand the error, you can print the length of the `com` array.

```
com = reader.next().toCharArray();
System.out.println(com.length); // prints 1 if input is '/'
```

When user inputs only a slash (/), the length is 1 even though you initialize the `com` array.

If you want your program to check if the user input is a comment or not, you need to update your code. To avoid such index out of bound exception, you should check the length of your `com` array before the if/else block.

Comment: Bro Wasi Ahmed. when the user enters for example /**/ it works. why single slash does't work. I have declared com array with length of 30.

Comment: I wan to get else part result and that is " It is not a comment"

Comment: @AbdirahmanWaaya i have updated my answer. I know what you have done! carefully read my answer, hopefully you should get your answer.

Comment: @AbdirahmanWaaya do a check to see if the length of your `com` array is greater than or equal to 2 or not. because according to your program, a comment must be of length 2 at least!

Answer (score 0):

you can only enter one char at time 
let me make it very clear :

```
`com[0] // the enter value will be in it `
`com[1] // there is no value here , `
//you can do the answer for it by putting in it inside of a loop
```

`loop(int i=0;i<30;i++){`

```
`enter code here`/ 
`check the number `/ 
 /if true break `enter code here`
 no need for else he will just go back to the start of the loop 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will clear your doubt -

**com = reader.next().toCharArray();** this line of your code will create a new char array and make "com" to refer to that array, that means now the **com.length;** will give the numbers of character that user entered not 30.

So if user enters "/", then com.length; will be one and access to com[1] in your loop will cause **java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException**.

Not only "/" but all the followings will also give the same exception -

1. /*some text...
2. /*some text.../
3. /*some text...* and many more except /*some text...*/

all because same above reason.

So you need to check for **com.legth;** and use com.length; in for loop instead of 30.It will also save you from unnecessary iterations.